# Unexpected CFBundle info.list

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bundle

I have a problem, upload one iOS APP in the AppleStore, return this message:

> ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at '/Payload/Mercados.app/AgroMercado/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

Update the pods, delete and create the CFBundlePackageType and  set BNDL... but not work.
Help :(

My Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>AWS</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CredentialsProvider</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CognitoIdentity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Default</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>PoolId</key>
                    <string>us-east-1:d4df68f8-825d-4052-a0d9-cbbf1b16cc16</string>
                    <key>Region</key>
                    <string>USEast1</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>MobileAnalytics</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>AppId</key>
                <string>2203ad8470a54fd2845b2ea07a9c0900</string>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>USEast1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Mercados</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>googleapis.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>sader.gob.mx</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Upload pictures taken with camera to register your products in App Mercados.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Activa Localización para que &quot;Apoyos Sagarpa&quot; identifique las ventanillas más cercas a tu ubicación.</string>
    <key>NSMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Upload pictures you&apos;ve taken to share product in App Mercados.</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>FF Clan OT Black.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Bold.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Book.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Medium.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow Black.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow Bold.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow Book.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow Medium.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow News.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow Thin.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Narrow Ultra.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT News.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Thin.otf</string>
        <string>FF Clan OT Ultra.otf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's required.

`CFBundleExecutable` usually points to `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)`
Ensure that:

The path specified appears to be your main app, not any Framework.

Open your app's Info.plist

1. The key is present
2. The value specified by the key exists and is
   correct

Here's some notes:

1. You should leave `CFBundleName` as `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`
2. You should leave `CFBundlePackageType` as `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)`

Try reverting those values as stated back to the apple defaults, and try again.

Comment: Yes, the key is "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)" and exist, but the message recived not change. :(

Comment: Have you ensured `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)` is the value of `CFBundlePackageType`. Please post your Info.plist if still stuck

Comment: Update my question...  Info.plist for my project

Comment: Added some notes after comparing to a clean Info.plist

Comment: Create one project new, change the values, and nothing, te response the apple team is equal.

Comment: What version of Xcode or application loader are you exporting with

Comment: Version 11.3.1 (11C504)